# How do I test the Facebook "Like" button on localhost?

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-like, localhost

It is possible to test "**Like**" button on localhost?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Dave's answer is correct, however, I just discovered a workaround: You can make your local machine accessible by using http://localtunnel.me . You'll need to (temporarily) change some URLs used in your app code / html so links point to the temporary domain, but at least facebook can reach your machine.

Comment: localtunnel is really convenient to test sharing meta description, title and image.

Comment: Thanks M.G.Palmer, localtunnel.com works like a charm! Here an announcement about localtunnel version 2: http://progrium.com/blog/2012/12/25/localtunnel-v2-available-in-beta/ Github: https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel/blob/master/README.md

Comment: New url: localtunnel.me

Answer (score 28):

Not really; facebook has to crawl your site to pull in the title, description, and thumbnail.  It can't get to your site if it's on localhost.

Comment: Related to what @M.G.Palmer mentioned, if you can get a public IP address or DNS entry for your local box, and make sure the box is accessible to the outside world, you could use that instead of 'localhost'.

Answer (score 10):

It *is* possible to perform limited testing on the facebook like button on localhost. It renders properly on my machine. The trick is using a live, non-localhost URL on the `data-href` attribute (I used Google in the sample below):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

Answer (score -4):

If you're developing the likebutton for www.xyz.com, just add in your hosts file:

127.0.0.1     www.xyz.com

Hooray, no more 500s.

Comment: This works considering that you already have a website at `www.xyz.com` with same pages as in your localhost.