# Facebook Like button not showing on localhost

Tags: facebook, localhost, facebook-like

The facebook like button is not showing up today on a website I am developing on localhost. Yet the exact same website shows the button shows the button when uploaded to my web server.

Any ideas why this might be happening? It was working fine yesterday, and I haven't changed the code.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595989/how-do-i-test-the-facebook-like-button-on-localhost

Answer (score 0):

Have you created virtual host on local server ?? reason is because you have set url of your webserver on facebook application settings , if you set url of your local host there then button will appear on your local website :)

Comment: I don't think that will fix this problem. You put the Like button code on any number of pages with any number of different urls. The url you used to make the button doesn't really matter. Right now I am looking at a page where I use an iframe Like button, with a php generated dynamic url. With an http://localhost url, the Like button does not show. When I upload the page to the remote production server, the Like button miraculously shows. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595989/how-do-i-test-the-facebook-like-button-on-localhost