# Facebook Like module not showing

Tags: c#-4.0, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've succesfully installed the Facebook Like module by fekke.

However when i add this module to layer (for example homepage) nothing is showing up except the Title.

When inspecting the widget with firebug i get the following code (only copied the main elements, the full code is not shown belong due the length):

```
<div class="zone zone-tripel-second">
<article class="widget-tripel-second widget-facebook-like-widget widget">
<header>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
<fb:like class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" colorscheme="" font="Lucida Grande" action="like" width="450" show_faces="show_faces" href="http://localhost:30320/OrchardLocal/" fb-xfbml-state="rendered">
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: header tag is not closed, are yous sure , that copied the code here well ?

Comment: Its copied from firebug, the entire code would be to long to paste. In my project all the tags are closed properly.

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595989/hot-to-test-like-button-on-localhost
Facebook button does not work on localhost.

Comment: Good catch Kovge. Seems I will be unable to test this until my site up and running.

Comment: Yep, nearly right, but in the same topic there is an answer where is a suggestion for testing on local machine ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595989/hot-to-test-like-button-on-localhost#8535503

Comment: True but i mean its to much hassle for such a small feature. Guess i will implement it once my site is up and running. Thanks again!