# Add Share Buttons to Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter, web

I know this is supposed to be easy task and I  have tried code from the developer sites of twitter and facebook as well but any of those code won't work.
I also tried from some other sites as well.

I have to put facebook/twitter share buttons in my webpage.Both the codes from the developer site are not working when I check then on XAMPP .

```
<html>
<head> Vamos </head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"></div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="TinyNote1">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In above code in Chrome browser nothing except the head element gets displayed.

Could you please find what am I doind wrong and what should I do ?

I tried using XFBML (Add an XML namespace to the  tag of your document.) but nothing worked for me.

Comment: you need to explain how they are not working. Are the scripts not getting included, are there errors on the javascript console, are the share buttons not opening a popup for the share?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I edited my question. Please check .

Comment: open the network tab (F12, click Network), reload the page are the scripts from twitter, facebook being retrieved?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think network is fine, I am not having trouble in retieving any scripts for other pages. This thing is not working anywhere, http://www.compileonline.com/try_html5_online.php based on developer instructions at twitter facebook they say only this much code is required , i wonder what is wrong

Comment: I just copied this code to my local and ran it on a local server and i am seeing the buttons as expected.  I tested Safari v7.1, Chrome v. 38, and Firefox v33 - all for mac.  Can you provide some other browser specs if you aren't using the latest builds?

Comment: @Roger Chrome 38 on Windows 8.1 but i have AD Block plus and ghostery chrome plugins installed could they be the reason ? Yes they are, I checked now. Still, after disabling them, I don't get the facebook button, Only tweet button is coming ?

Comment: I just run the code and it works. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/carlodurso/7pbr5fsq/). Definitely something wrong with your machine. Try disabling XAMPP.

Comment: @carlodurso  In your link I wonder why isn't the facebook button working ? I have the code for facebook also. Could you say why it isn't working ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @carlodurso Are you also getting the Facebook button in your browser ?

Comment: Looks like something wrong with facebook sdk. Locally I get this warning in the console: _fb:share_button failed to resize in 45s_

Comment: not a problem. I'll let you know if I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Florentino, I tested the Facebook social plugin on my server and it's working as expected. [Same issue as the one described in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595989/how-do-i-test-the-facebook-like-button-on-localhost).